# Referencing array in smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am trying to reference an array through a function I am calling

```
$bio['results'] = $db->query(sprintf('SELECT * FROM `athlete_bio_results` WHERE `PersonID` = %d ORDER BY `athlete_bio_results`.`Type` DESC, `athlete_bio_results`.`Date` DESC;', $id));

    $smarty->assign(value($params, 'to', 'athlete'), $bio);
```

In my view I am referencing through a foreach loop some of the fields through this array.

How would I reference a field outside of this foreach loop for checking..For instance in the foreach loop I can go {$result.Type) which will bring up everything in the db under that field. I want to check for a certain type before the foreach loop. My problem is referencing that piece of data outside the foreach loop. How would I achieve this? Thanks!

```
{if $athlete.results['Type'] == 'National'} <---- This is not working for me.
    {foreach $athlete.results as $result}
        {$result.Date|substr:0:-6} 
        {$result.Event} - 
        {$result.Result}
            {if $result.Junior == 'no' || $result.Junior == ''}
            {else}
                {'(Jr. Div.)'}
            {/if}
        <br />
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

**EDIT**

This is the code that works

```
{foreach $athlete.results as $result}
    {if $result['Type'] == 'National'}
        {$result.Date|substr:0:-6} 
        {$result.Event} - 
        {$result.Result}
            {if $result.Junior == 'no' || $result.Junior == ''}
            {else}
                {'(Jr. Div.)'}
            {/if}
    <br />
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Thanks for your help in guiding me to the right solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're accessing the first element of the array, use the key `[0]`:

```
{if $athlete.results[0]['Type'] == 'National'}
```

Actually I'm not certain that will work. If it doesn't, try this syntax instead.

```
{if $athlete.results[0].Type == 'National'}
```

**EDIT**
Should you be checking Type inside the `foreach`?

```
{foreach $athlete.results as $result}
  {* Check inside the loop... *}
  {if $result['Type'] == 'National'}
    {$result.Date|substr:0:-6} 
    {$result.Event} - 
    {$result.Result}
        {if $result.Junior == 'no' || $result.Junior == ''}
        {else}
            {'(Jr. Div.)'}
        {/if}
    <br />
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Do you get any output if you just place `{$athlete.results[0].Type}` into the template?

Comment: Also, what is the `value()` function in ` $smarty->assign(value($params, 'to', 'athlete'), $bio);`  ? that's not a PHP built-in function afaik.

Comment: Okay this worked and I got data back but I got two sets of data back not just the national.

{if $athlete.results[0].Type == 'National'}

Comment: Can you just `$smarty->assign('athlete', $bio['results']);`?

Comment: The second set of data being International

Comment: Before assigning to Smarty, `print_r()` on your results so you are certain they are organized as you expect.  There is no reason that the conditional `{if}` would fail to match `"National"`

Comment: I got this back [Type] => National when I did print_r($bio['results']);

Comment: I have two sets of type being National and International. How do I limit only to National? My foreach loop is still going through every result.

Comment: Wait a minute, I think I'm starting to understand this. Do you really mean to check the value of Type _inside_ the foreach? See my edit above in a minute or two...

Comment: I am checking the type now with your code and I am getting nothing back as of now. Yeah I am checking for the type inside for the foreach loop. I only want my national set of data to come back.

Comment: I got it!! In your first part of the loop you want

{if $result['Type'] == 'National'}